# When thread release its resources

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, process, pthreads

In man page of `pthread_detach` i read that when any thread is detached then at a time of thread termination it release its resources back to system.

What are thread resources?Is that it is a part of memory used by that thread, if it is so then that memory is a part of a process address space. I am trying to understand this but i dint got it.

And what about the joinable thread, when does thread release its resources? at a time of `pthread_join` or at a time of termination or process?

When resources are released in  `pthread_cancel` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every thread consumes some amount of bookkeeping resources in the operating system, as well as its own execution stack in userspace memory. Those resources are freed when the thread is destroyed, which can occur under several conditions, such as:

- `pthread_join` returns when called on a joinable thread,
- a detached thread's entry function returns,
- `main` returns normally or `exit` is called,
- the process is terminated due to receiving an unhandled signal,
- `exec` is called successfully.

It is possible, however, to exit the thread that is running `main` and leave other, detached threads running. To do so, you have to call `pthread_exit` in the main thread.

Comment: What about `pthread_cancel` and a thread returns and not joined by main thread?

Comment: @Abhiteshkhatri: Cancellation is immaterial to the discussion. You still have to join the thread, especially if you want to know whether the cancellation had any effect. See [the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html) for details.